# Determine the Conditional Extremes of a Function

Tags: partial-derivative, conditional-expectation, extreme-value-theorem

I am trying to determine the conditional extremes the following question:

- Determine the point of the plane, $2x-y+2z=16$ closest to the origin.

but I do not fully understand the question. If I am interpreting the question correctly then:

1. The function would be: $f(x,y,z) = 2x+2y+2z=16$.
2. The condition would be something like $x + y = ?$.

But I am not sure how exactly to interpret the condition from the question. Any suggestions?

Comment: use the Hessian Normalform of your plane

Comment: I am not aware of that concept. Could you please explain?

Comment: see here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HessianNormalForm.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distance of a point $(x,y,z)$ in the plane and the origin, $(0,0,0)$, is equal to

$$ ||(x,y,z)|| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} .$$

So the problem you describe can be written as

$$ \min_{x,y,z} x^2+y^2+z^2\quad\text{subject to} \quad 2x−y+2z=16.$$

The first order conditions are:
\begin{align}
[x]:&\quad 2x+2\lambda=0\\ 
[y]:&\quad 2y-\lambda=0\\ 
[z]:&\quad 2z+2\lambda=0
\end{align}
where $\lambda$ is the Lagrange multiplier. Solving this system yields
$$ x=-\lambda,\quad y=\frac{\lambda}{2},\quad\text{and}\quad z=-\lambda.$$

Substituting this into the constraint we get

$$-2\lambda-\frac{\lambda}{2}-2\lambda=16 \Rightarrow \lambda=-\frac{32}{9}.$$

Finally, the point can be solve for by plugging $\lambda$ back:
$$ x=\frac{32}{9},\quad y=-\frac{32}{18},\quad\text{and}\quad z=\frac{32}{9},$$

and the associated distance is
$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}=\frac{16}{3}. $$

Answer (score 1):

the Hessian Normalform of your equation is given by 
$$\frac{2x-y+2z-16}{\pm3}$$ Setting $P(0;0;0)$ in the given term we get the disatnce to the origo to the plane this is given by $$\frac{16}{3}$$

Comment: Thank you, I now understand this part but how do I make that into my condition? Would it be $x+y=\frac{16}{3}$?